# Why doesn't my Nvidia GeForce 610 work with a VGA switch?

Tags: vga, kvm-switch

I have two computers connected to one monitor using a VGA switch. for one computer, it is using onboard vga. And it can show image to monitor when vga switch is turn to it. However, another computer is using an Nvidia GeForce GT 610, and it cannot display image when the switch is turned to it. But it does work when connected directly to a monitor.

I found some forum posts that say the card settings are bad.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would check first is if the KVM cable itself is working. Try swapping the KVM cables to see if the problem moves or not.

Comment: Hello all. I have swap the cable. However , it is still not working. The cable can work in other computer. So it must have some setting in display card or windows 7. Please help. Thanks